# How to split code into different python files

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been working on an I/O bound application where I will run multiple scripts at the same time depending on the args I will call for a script etc: monitor.py --s="sydsvenskan", monitor.py -ss="bbc" etc etc.

```
from __future__ import annotations

from abc import abstractmethod
from typing import ClassVar, Dict
from typing import Optional

import attr
import requests
from selectolax.parser import HTMLParser


@attr.dataclass
class Info:
    """Scraped info about news"""
    all_articles: set = attr.ib(factory=set)
    store: str = attr.ib(factory=str)
    name: Optional[str] = attr.ib(factory=str)
    image: Optional[str] = attr.ib(factory=str)


class Scraper:
    scrapers: ClassVar[Dict[str, Scraper]] = {}
    domain: ClassVar[str]

    def __init_subclass__(cls) -> None:
        Scraper.scrapers[cls.domain] = cls

    @classmethod
    def for_url(cls, domain, url) -> Scraper:
        return cls.scrapers[domain](url)

    @abstractmethod
    def scrape_feed(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def scrape_product(self):
        pass


class BBCScraper(Scraper):
    domain = 'BBC'

    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url

    def scrape_feed(self):
        with requests.get(self.url) as rep:
            # FIXME Better way than this atleast :P
            if rep:
                doc = HTMLParser(rep.text)

                all_articles = {
                    f"https://www.BBC.se{product_link.attrs['href']}" for product_link in
                    doc.css('td.search-productnamne > a, div.product-image > a')
                }

                return Info(
                    store="BBC",
                    all_articles=all_articles
                )

    def scrape_product(self):
        with requests.get(self.url) as rep:
            # FIXME Better way than this atleast :P
            if rep:
                doc = HTMLParser(rep.text)

                # FIXME Scrape valid webelements
                name = "Test"
                image = "Test"

                return Info(
                    store="BBC",
                    name=name,
                    image=image,
                )


class SydsvenskanScraper(Scraper):
    domain = 'Sydsvenskan'

    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url

    def scrape_feed(self):
        with requests.get(self.url) as rep:
            # FIXME Better way than this atleast :P
            if rep:
                doc = HTMLParser(rep.text)

                all_articles = {
                    f"https://Sydsvenskan.se/{product_link.attrs['href']}" for product_link in
                    doc.css('div.product-image > a, td.search-productnamne > a')
                }

                return Info(
                    store="Sydsvenskan",
                    all_articles=all_articles
                )

    def scrape_product(self):
        with requests.get(self.url) as rep:
            # FIXME Better way than this atleast :P
            if rep:
                doc = HTMLParser(rep.text)

                # FIXME Scrape valid webelements
                name = "Test"
                image = "Test"

                return Info(
                    store="Sydsvenskan",
                    name=name,
                    image=image,
                )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    #FIXME Use arguments instead
    domain = 'BBC'
    url = 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/'
    scraper = Scraper.for_url(domain, url)
    r = scraper.scrape_feed()
    print(r)
```

As you can currently see I have "hardcoded":

```
domain = 'BBC'
url = 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/'
```

which will currently be passed through arguments instead.

However as we can see if I start to add more "stores/news sites" in the `class Scraper` e.g. 40 different site, it would be pretty hard to navigate to the correct code if you want to maintain or do any changes.

I wonder how I can in that case split the code into different files where etc Sydsvenska will be for itself and BBC will be by itself. I can then easier maintain the code in the future if there will be any changes.

Comment: I'm just checking something here. You seem to be knowledgeable about python. You have type hinting with abstract classes and all this. But your question seems like you don't know how to cut and paste code into another file and then import that file into the script. Is that the case? If not can you be more specific on what you're looking for?

Comment: I would say indeed. I do know abit python but also got great tutorials to follow to understand more. @Mythalorian, My real problem is that I do not know how I can split it in a "nice way". Meaning that instead of having all the scrapes in one script file to have it split. The only thing I can think of is to cut the code into multiple files and then import it into the `class Scraper` but is it necessary to scrape import 40 different sites if we are only going to use one based on the arguments that we enter? (Im also trying to avoid the dynamic import as well if thats a scenario)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I understand what you're looking for. And sorry to say you're out of luck. At least as far as my knowledge of python goes. You can do it two ways.

1. Use importlib to search through a folder/package tha contains those files and imports them into a list or dict to be retrieved. However you said you wanted to avoid this but either way you would have to use importlib. And #2 is the reason why.
2. Use a Base class that when inherited it's `__init__` call adds the Derived class to a list or object that stores it and you can retrieve it via a class object. However the issue here is that if you move your derived class into a new file, that code wont run until you import it. So you would still need to explicitly import the file or implicitly import it via importlib (dynamic import).

So you'll have to use importlib (dynamic import) either way.

Comment: Oh I see, so both ends up either way to use importlib if I want to import only the needed news I want to monitor if I am correct. Does it matter/sense to import all news stores (even if they are 40) or is it better to use dynamic to only import the one needed?

Comment: If this was a server or a continuously running process then yes I would suggest importing all 40. But seems like your script is a one-shot. In that case I would just dynamically import only what you need. If every time you run your script it imports 40 modules but you only use one than it's pointless and will slowdown start up time.

Comment: But is it only the startup that will be slowdowned or will the whole application be slowed too if you run it 24/7? Since its a webscraping/web crawling application. It will be running 24/7. If that would be a good information to add :) But yes my script will be one-shot since I will use arguments to run specific news store. But again, if it just at the start it is slow then I would be fine to implement all imports then?

Comment: Sorry let me clarify. I should remove continuously running process. Really you should import all 40 if it was a server where you send it a request that could be for any of the 40.  And it will only slow down startup cause once you do a dynamic import you don't need to do it again unless the program exits. Just make sure to save a reference to the module you dynamically imported and use that to make calls.

Comment: Right, by using dynamic imports, wouldnt I lose the way on how to call dataclass? By that I mean when we do this code in pycharm: `r = scraper.scrape_feed()
    print(r.store) # or .all_prodcurs` where it wouldnt suggest which dataclass I can use?

Comment: I'm not following what you mean. I see the part of the code you are referring too but I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: So the example I have in the question, when I call r. in pycharm, it would suggest me which dataclass I could use which would be from the `class Info` and thst could be r.store, r.name. However when I use the dynamic import it wouldnt show me the suggestion anymore it seems... but if I use static import then it will show

Comment: Ohh you're referring to autocompletion inside Pycharm. My suggestion would to use type hinting. Remember python doesn't enforce types with type hinting. So you can easily just do this. `r: Info = scraper.scrape_feed()`. Now Pycharm should autocomplete for you.

Comment: It's also very helpful that you created a base class that all others inherit from. Which helps a lot with autocompletion with type hinting. Since now you can "cast" to the base class and get autocomplete for anything that inherits that base class.

Comment: Oh I didnt knew that type hinting would do that I can use the autocomplete. I would need to try to do that. However I was reading your answer #2 regarding init but im not quite sure how I can do that, Do you maybe have a small example where I can begin with? 

Comment: #2 is what you already did inside of `__init_subclass__` except I said `__init__`. But if you're doing dynamic import I would avoid using #2 method and just stick with #1.

Comment: I will give that a go! I need to find out first how to import with importlib first. Didnt succeed by just import the sub file that I want. I think I need a init file for it? Not quite sure how it works with importlib yet

Comment: Good start would be here I think. I've used importlib for something similar to what you're talking about, but that was a few years ago. But import to remember is it uses package name style importing and not folder based. https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module